# Date is returning null

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android application with a users list and I'm trying to get the age from the users.

I'm getting all the data from a json file, and I'm receiving the Birthday date like this:

```
"birth_date":"1965-05-07"
```

Now, I'm trying to parse the Year, month and date, and get the age from the users.

```
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String user_id = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
    String birth_date = c.getString(TAG_BIRTH_DATE);
    String pic_url_get = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

    int year = Integer.parseInt(birth_date.substring(0, 4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(birth_date.substring(4, 6));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(birth_date.substring(birth_date.length() - 2));

    Calendar dateOfYourBirth = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yourAge = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dateOfYourBirth.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    dateOfYourBirth.add(Calendar.YEAR, yourAge);
    if (today.before(dateOfYourBirth)) {
        yourAge--;
    }        

    // tmp hashmap for single contact
    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    contact.put(TAG_BIRTH_DATE, "Age" + yourAge);
    contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, "*******/images/" + user_id + "/" + pic_url_get);


    // adding contact to contact list
    contactList.add(contact);
}
```

Errors that i am receiving:

```
04-19 16:32:20.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19736): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
04-19 16:32:20.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19736):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-19 16:32:20.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19736):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
04-19 16:32:20.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19736):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
04-19 16:32:20.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19736):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: `birth_date.substring(4, 6)` - Don't you mean `5, 7`?

Comment: can you print out the `birth_date` value ? seems like the value is `"null"` (a string with value "null")

Comment: When i print the birth_date I receive all birth days, I didn't find null birthdays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not reinvent [the wheel](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Formatters):

```
// replace your birth_date substring calls with this
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime birthDate = fmt.parse(birth_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with do you actually get the data from the user(`json` object)?
Can you put break points at this String

```
birth_date = c.getString(TAG_BIRTH_DATE);
```

do you get the `birthdate`?

Comment: I forgot to post the string: private static final String TAG_BIRTH_DATE = "birth_date"; I'm getting all the values, when I print the values, everything works fine, the problem is the parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's own date formatter.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

Date birthDate = formatter.parse(birth_date);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html